# Can't post an image extracted from ImageView on Facebook on ios with Titanium

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, titanium

I'm trying to add some facebook functionality to a app and I'm making some test.
I'd like to transform an `ImageView` (self.iconImage) to a blob and post
to facebook.
But I'm getting this error:

> [ERROR] : message = "*** Collection <__NSDictionaryM: 0x7fb6217d2030>
>   was mutated while being enumerated.";

This is the code.

```
shareView.addEventListener('click',function(){
      var blob = self.iconImage.toImage(); // I have tried also toBlob
      var fb = require('facebook');
      fb.permissions = ['publish_actions'];
      fb.initialize();
      if(!fb.loggedIn)
        fb.authorize();

      function postPoi(){
          var post = {picture: blob, caption:"test",message:"test"};
          fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/feed',post , "POST")});   
      }
      fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
        if (e.success) 
            postPoi();  
      });   
});
```

The error is related to the blob: if I remove picture from post object I can post to facebook.
Any Idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What version of the Titanium SDK and/or Facebook module are you using? This was fixed by https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-18916 in Titanium SDK 4.0.1 and Facebook module 4.0.4